# Class 'Dotenv\\Environment\\Adapter\\PutenvAdapter' not found

Tags: php, phpdotenv

I have an Ubuntu installation on WSL. Everything was ok the last time I used it to develop the same website.
Today I started apache2 and mysql as always but the website is not working.
The two lines in apache log file are:

```
PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '/var/www/nailsacademy.test/vendor/composer/../vlucas/phpdotenv/src/Environment/Adapter/PutenvAdapter.phpr/composer/../vlucas/phpdotenv/src/Environment/Adapter/ServerConstAdapter.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/nailsacademy.test/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444
```

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Dotenv\\Environment\\Adapter\\PutenvAdapter' not found in /var/www/nailsacademy.test/vendor/vlucas/phpdotenv/src/Environment/DotenvFactory.php:34\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/nailsacademy.test/vendor/vlucas/phpdotenv/src/Dotenv.php(49): Dotenv\\Environment\\DotenvFactory->__construct()\n#1 /var/www/nailsacademy.test/app/config/_env.php(13): Dotenv\\Dotenv::create('/var/www/nailsa...')\n#2 /var/www/nailsacademy.test/bootstrap/init.php(12): require_once('/var/www/nailsa...')\n#3 /var/www/nailsacademy.test/public/index.php(3): require_once('/var/www/nailsa...')\n#4 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/nailsacademy.test/vendor/vlucas/phpdotenv/src/Environment/DotenvFactory.php on line 34
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Dotenv wasn’t autoloaded properly -- which means something likely went wrong with Composer.

I suggest making sure Composer is working as expected, run `composer install` and then verify that `vlucas/phpdotenv` is in your vendor folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue due to entire project files are replace with new project then i tried following step,

1. I have take backup of vendor folder and then run `composer install` command in terminal.
2. then try to run project again and its working fine. Then removed backup vendor folder.